# Centralizer of the matrix $I+E_{ij} (i\ne j)$ in $SL_n(k)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

**Question:**

a) Let $C_{ij}$ be the centralizer of the matrix $I+E_{ij}$. Find explicit generators of $C_{ij}$.

b) Find the intersection $\bigcap_{i\neq j}C_{ij}$.

c) Determine all the elements in the conjugacy class of $I+E_{ij}$.

**Answer:**

a) Let $X\in C_{ij}$. Then $X(I+E_{ij})=(I+E_{ij})X$, which implies $XE_{ij}=E_{ij}X$. By computing the multiplications on the latter equation, we obtain

$$\begin{bmatrix}
0&\cdots&0&*&0&\cdots&0\\ 
0&\cdots&0&*&0&\cdots&0\\
\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&0\\
0&\cdots&0&*&0&\cdots&0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
    0&0&\cdots&0\\
    \vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
    0&0&\cdots&0\\
    *&*&\cdots&*\\
    0&0&\cdots&0\\
    \vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
    0&0&\cdots&0
\end{bmatrix}$$

($j$th row and $i$th column). This would imply that except $x_{jj}$, $j$th row of $X$ must be all zero and except $x_{ii}$, $i$th column must be all zero. Also, $X_{jj}=x_{ii}$. Thus, $X$ must be of the following form

$$X=\begin{bmatrix}
    \ddots&&0&&&&\\
    &\ddots&\vdots&&&&\\
    &&1&&&&\\
    &&\vdots&\ddots&&&\\
    0&\cdots&\vdots&\cdots&1&\cdots&0\\
    &&\vdots&&&\ddots&\\
    &&0&&&&\ddots
\end{bmatrix}.$$

However, I couldn't exactly find the generators of $C_{ij}$.

b) Since $i$ and $j$ varies, by the above observations, a matrix from the intersection must be diagonal. Moreover, all diagonal entries must be the same. Hence, the intersection is just ${I}$ if $n$ is odd and ${\pm I}$ if $n$ is even.

c) I just couldn't find any trick for this part. Any helps/hints would be appreciated. Thanks in advance...

Comment: What is $E_{ij}$ ? If it's an elementary matrix, then it's determinant is $-1$ unless it's the identity, so they are not in the special linear group, neither is $I+{E_{ij}},$ unless I am grossly mistaken.

Comment: Comment on your solution for (b).Yes, the centraliser is the set of diagonal matrices in $SL_n(k)$. As the determinant is $1$ they must be of the form $\zeta I$ where $\zeta$ is an $n$-th root of unity. [But you need to answer @dezdichado 's queries]

Comment: @dezdichado The determinant of $E_{ij}$ is $0$, the determinant of $I+E_{ij}$ is $1$. (I think you've read $E_{ij}$ as the swapping matrix, it's not.)

Comment: @ancientmathematician Yes, $E_{ij}$ is just the matrix where $ij$th entry is 1 but all the others are 0. How about the part (a) and (c)?

Comment: Sorry. I can describe the centraliser of $I+E_{12}$ and I suppose that the set of all matrices in it will be a set of generators, but surely something else must be intended? And I have no idea how to describe the conjugacy class of $I+E_{12}$.